# Apply arithmetic into piped command

Tags: find, pipe, xargs, arithmetic, stat

So far I have this:

```
sudo find /path/to/dir -type f |
  xargs -d "\n" sudo stat -c "%Y %n" | 
    {arithmetic to check if %Y is between 1685518962 and 1685624474??} | 
      {show file path}
```

To note, I am aware of `find -newermt` but am more generally asking about performing arithmetic in the command line.

To clarify, I am hoping for a one-liner.

TCSH or BASH are acceptable to me but don't hesitate to enlighten me with another shell.

Comment: don't do `find … | xargs …`. At the very least, do `find … -print0| xargs -0 …`, or better, use `find`'s `--exec`. Or, use your shell's recursive globbing instead of `find` alltogether. (Depends on which shell you're using.)

Comment: Also, note you're not doing arithmetics in your example, you're doing comparisons.

Comment: Also, what's your shell? That defines what kind of arithmetics you can do with the shell itself.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Depends on the definition. ["In general, arithmetic deals with all of the basic notions of numbers, including place value and **comparisons**."](https://www.storyofmathematics.com/arithmetic/)

Comment: Any code can be put on one line, though that rarely helps with legibility. What's the reason for wanting it on one line?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I wish to modify it instantly and hit Enter and I find some enjoyment in code-golfing Linux. Resorting to a `.sh` file just means I could have resorted to something familiar like PHP or PERL.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, most modern shells will let you enter multiline code at their prompt and edit it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas There is clearly much for me to learn. I'm not discrediting shell file nor multi-line answers, I'll happily upvote them =)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, arithmetic deals with integer numbers. Comparaisons are not specific to this kind of numbers. Arithmetic is more about divisibility.

Comment: @InfiniteLooper, bash builtin arithmetic deal with integer only but that's a limitation of that shell. zsh, ksh93, fish, yash... can deal with floating points alright. In any case, the *arithmetic* Engish word is not about integers.

Answer (score 9):

Use NUL-delimited records (`-print0` for `find`, `-0` for `xargs`) to process file lists, not lines as newline is as valid as any other character (or non-character) in a file path.

Since you're already using GNU extensions, here you can do:

```
sudo find /path/to/dir -type f '(' \
   -newermt @1685518962 ! -newermt @1685624474 -exec something with {} + \
   -o -exec something-else with {} + ')'
```

GNU `find` has had the ability to report metadata from files (with a much better interface) long before a GNU `stat` command was introduced. For post-processing you can use anything that supports NUL-delimited records and floating point arithmetic such as gawk/mawk, perl or zsh:

```
sudo find -H /path/to/dir -type f -printf '%T@\0%p\0' |
  LC_ALL=C gawk -v RS='\0' -F: '
    {mtime = $0; getline file}
    mtime > 1685518962 && mtime <= 1685624474 {
      # something with mtime and file
    }'
```

With `perl`:

```
sudo find -H /path/to/dir -type f -printf '%T@\0%p\0' | perl -0lne '
  $mtime = $_; $file = <>;
  if ($mtime > 1685518962 && $mtime <= 1685624474) {
    # something with $mtime and $file
  }'
```

Any code including any of the examples given here can be put on one line. If it's a golfing exercise, `perl` would likely be the most adapted of them:

```
sudo find -H /path/to/dir -type f -printf '%p\0%T@\0'|perl -0lne'$m=<>;{...}if$m>1685518962&&$m<=1685624474'
```

Or if using `zsh`, in case you need a shell to get involved in the processing of those files:

```
sudo find -H /path/to/dir -type f -printf '%T@/%p\0' |
  while IFS=/ read -rd '' mtime file; do
    (( mtime > 1685518962 && mtime <= 1685624474 )) &&
      something with $mtime and $file
  done
```

Though `zsh` also has most of `find`'s feature builtin, and a builtin `stat` (which predates GNU `stat`), which would avoid having to depend on GNUisms though would likely be slower:

```
sudo zsh -c '
  zmodload zsh/stat
  for file ( /path/to/dir/**/*(ND.) ) {
    stat -LF %s.%N -A mtime +mtime -- $file &&
      (( mtime > 1685518962 && mtime <= 1685624474 )) &&
      something with $file and $mtime
  }'
```

I wouldn't use tcsh in this day and age as it's virtually impossible to do anything reliably with it, but since you mention it, note that it does support recursive globbing (copied from zsh in 2010, shortly after bash), and has builtin support to retrieve a file's mtime, though not with subsecond precision (anyway its arithmetic is integer only) and only after symlink resolution.

```
set globstar globdot
foreach file ( /path/to/dir/** )
  if ( -f $file:q && ! -l $file:q ) then
    @ mtime = -M $file:q
    if ( $mtime > 1685518962 && $mtime <= 1685624474 ) then
      something with $file:q and $mtime
    endif
  endif
end
```

Note that though the other ones get the mtime with full nanosecond precision, the `double` floating point number type of most computers/C-compilers and as a consequence of `awk`/`perl`/`zsh`¹ can't hold as much precision as needed for today's timestamp.

For instance, most of those would fail to report a file last modified at `1685518962.000000001`. Likely not a big problem in your case; that may become so if you needed to find files last modified within a given microsecond with high precision for instance.

Another note: because `sudo` passes a `SUDO_COMMAND` environment variable to the command it executes, and that variable contains all the arguments, that means that `xargs sudo cmd` is likely to fail with a *"too many arguments"* error if there is a large number of files as the `execve()` limit is on the cumulative size of arguments and environment strings, so while `xargs` will manage to run `sudo`, `sudo` may fail to run `cmd` as the cumulative size doubles inbetween.

For that reason, and also because it saves running some `sudo` invocations, it's better to use `sudo xargs cmd`. Here you could also invoke `sudo` only once with `sudo sh -c '...'`

---

<sup>¹ that can be worked around with `-MvPREC=100` options in recent versions of `gawk` if arbitrary precision arithmetic has been enabled at build time, or with `-Mbignum` in `perl`, or more generally by comparing the seconds and nanoseconds separately (like `-newertmt` or shells/`[`'s `-nt` operators likely do) or the numbers using numeric string comparisons instead of converting them to fixed size binaries, like with `() [[ $1 = ${${(n)@}[1]} ]] $t1 $t2` instead of `(( t1 < t2 ))` in `zsh` using the `n`umeric sort parameter expansion flag.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a job for `awk`:

```
sudo find /path/to/dir -type f |
  xargs -d "\n" sudo stat -c "%Y %n" |
  awk '$1 > 1685518962 && $1 < 1685624474 {print}'
```

You can drop `xargs` by using the `-execdir` option to `find`:

```
sudo find /path/to/dir -type f -execdir stat -c "%Y %n" {} + |
  awk '$1 > 1685518962 && $1 < 1685624474 {print}'
```

Comment: This will fail if the file names contain newline characters, as usual. It might be safer to have something like `... stat -c "file: %Y %n" | awk '$1 == "file:" && $2 > 1683907726 && $2 < 1684446830  {print}'`.

Comment: If you use `-execdir`, the output will be missing the path of the directory where the files are found.

Answer (score 2):

Well, bash being acceptable

```bash
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s dotglob globstar extglob nullglob

oldest=1685518962
newest=1685624474

for file in **/*; do
  # check for regular file-ness
  modtime=$(stat -c '%Y' -- "${file}")
  [[ ( ! -L ${file} ) \
    && -f ${file} \
    && (  ${modtime} -gt ${oldest} ) \
    && (  ${modtime} -le ${newest} ) ]] \
  && {
    # do stuff
  }
done
```

Zsh is a bit prettier in what the globbing can do without any ado

```bash
#!/usr/bin/zsh
zmodload zsh/stat

oldest=1685518962
newest=1685624474

for file in **/*(.ND); do
  modtime=$(zstat -L +mtime -- "${file}")
  [[  ${modtime} -gt ${oldest}  \
  &&  ${modtime} -le ${newest} ]] \
  && {
    # do stuff
  }
done
```

Because your question *literally* asks for arithmetics, I'll point out that both zsh and bash support arithmetic operations in expansion: `$(( ${modtime} - ${oldest} ))` will give you the seconds since the lower-limit second. Zsh's arithmetics capabilities are a bit better, especially when it comes to floating point.

Comment: `[ -f` returns true for symlinks to regular files while `-type f` or zsh's `.` qualifier excludes them.

Comment: `zsh` has had a `stat` builtin long before GNU coreutils added one.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas re: `[ -f`: `man 1 bash` tells me it matches *regular files*; bit surprised it would match symlinks?

Comment: Ah, the dotglob omission is definitely a bug, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: That check for type is done after symlink resolution. A symlink to a regular file can be seen as a regular file. It's the intention of links to provide other paths to a same file. Sometimes it's desirable to consider those as if they were the target (like `stat()` or `[` does except with `-L`/`-h`) and sometimes not (ilke `lstat()`)

Comment: So, in the bash version, exclusing symlinks via symlink test `-L` should work.

Comment: Yes, `[ -f ... ]` <-> `-xtype f` <-> `(-.)`, `[ -f .. ] && [ ! -L ... ] <-> `-type f` <-> `(.)`.

Comment: Don't use `-o` / `-a`, those are deprecated and make for unreliable expressions. With bash specifically, the above fails with an error for a file called `=` for instance. Either use `[[ ... ]]` and its `&&`/`||` or use several `[` invocations chained with `&&` / `||` shell operators. Invoking split+glob on those $modtime/$oldest... makes little sense.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks! Don't get what you mean with "split+glob", though :(

Comment: See [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)

Comment: You don't want to quote those `(`, `)` inside `[[...]]`. Inside `[[...]]` (they're also not needed), there's also no split+glob so while they don't harm the quotes around expansions are not needed (except on the right side of the `=` and `!=` operator and they also have an effect for `=~`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I don't think I even need them

Comment: No, you don't. You also don't need the backslashes in zsh. `(( mtime > oldest && mtime <= newest ))` like in my answer also makes it more legible.

Comment: You're missing a `-- "$file"` to pass the file path to `stat`. Note that as I mention above and in my answer, zsh has a builtin `stat` (which predates GNU's of BSD's by several years) so using it would make it orders of magnitude faster. GNU `stat` also fails on a file called `-`.

Comment: Arithmetic expansion using `$((…))` is a POSIX shell feature, so not specific to zsh and bash.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas am I not using the builtin in a `$()`, but the external executable?

Comment: `stat -c` is GNU `stat` syntax, different from zsh builtin, different from BSD stat. To enable the builtin, you need `zmodload zsh/stat`. In any case, if you use `$(...)`, that's forking a process. Use the `-A` or `-H` to store the result into a variable. See my answer for an example.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas ah, thanks, that was the pointer I needed1

Comment: You still need `zmodload zsh/stat` if you use the `zstat` variant. These days, `compaudit` as you may be using through your completion configuration does a `zmodload -F zsh/stat b:zstat` to load the module and only enable the zstat builtin from it which is why you may find it's already enabled at the prompt of an interactive shell.

Comment: For GNU stat, that's `stat -c %Y -- "$file"`, not `stat -c -- '%Y'`.

Comment: Note that zsh `stat` is an interface to `stat()` by default. Add a `-L` for it to be an interface to `lstat()` and for symlink retrieve the information about the link itself. That's reversed with GNU `stat`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas oh man my script has more bugs than lines at this point ;)

Answer (score -1):

Notwithstanding the advice of other answers, *in general*, you'll need to combine two commands to create a one-liner shell arithmetic filter function you can use in a pipeline:

1. `xargs` ability to map over input lines, with
2. `sh` to access shell arithmetic functions

in the pattern `xargs -L1 sh -c '_() { ... }; _ "$@"'`

To your specific example, that would look like:

```
find ...
  | xargs stat ...
  | xargs -L1 sh -c '_() { [ 1685518962 -le $0 -a $0 -le 1685624474 ] && echo $@; }; _ "$@"'
```

This works for quick and dirty tasks, like the one you have here. If you have any data volume, though, you really want to deploy a tool that has the map-reduce functionality built in, like `awk`.

Comment: Oh, random down voter, please why?